# how to kubectl port-forward GitLab webservice?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I have deploy `helm upgrade --install gitlab gitlab/gitlab --timeout 600s -f gitlab.yaml`

gitlab.yaml is here, ip is `minikube ip`.

```yaml
# values-minikube.yaml
# This example intended as baseline to use Minikube for the deployment of GitLab
# - Services that are not compatible with how Minikube runs are disabled
# - Configured to use 192.168.99.100, and nip.io for the domain

# Minimal settings
global:
  ingress:
    configureCertmanager: false
    class: "nginx"
  hosts:
    domain: "${ip}.nip.io"
    externalIP: "${ip}"
  rails:
    bootsnap:
      enabled: false
  shell:
    # Configure the clone link in the UI to include the high-numbered NodePort
    # value from below (gitlab.gitlab-shell.service.nodePort)
    port: 32022
  psql:
    host: ${POSTGRES_K8S_SERVICE}
    database: postgres
    username: postgres
    password:
      secret: ${POSTGRES_K8S_SERVICE}
      key: postgresql-password
# Don't use certmanager, we'll self-sign
certmanager:
  install: false
# Use the "ingress" addon, not our Ingress (can't map 22/80/443)
nginx-ingress:
  enabled: false
# Save resources, only 3 CPU
prometheus:
  install: false
gitlab-runner:
  install: false
# Reduce replica counts, reducing CPU & memory requirements
gitlab:
  webservice:
    minReplicas: 1
    maxReplicas: 1
  sidekiq:
    minReplicas: 1
    maxReplicas: 1
  gitlab-shell:
    minReplicas: 1
    maxReplicas: 1
    # Map gitlab-shell to a high-numbered NodePort to support cloning over SSH since
    # Minikube takes port 22.
    service:
      type: NodePort
      nodePort: 32022
registry:
  hpa:
    minReplicas: 1
    maxReplicas: 1
```

After deploying, it will generate several ingresses, but **we cannot access them by using external machine**.
[image]

So I try to forward them by

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/gitlab-webservice-default 9000:8080 --address 0.0.0.0
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/gitlab-webservice-default 9001:8081 --address 0.0.0.0
```

8080 are from `ingress/gitlab-webservice-default`.  **9001** cannot be access, It means I cannot access https

```
  rules:
    - host: gitlab.192.168.49.2.nip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: gitlab-webservice-default
              servicePort: 8181
          - path: /admin/sidekiq
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: gitlab-webservice-default
              servicePort: 8080
```

But it seems not work when I try to login.

> 422
>
> The change you requested was rejected. Make sure you have access to the thing you tried to change.
>
> Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is a mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue is poorly documented via gitlab itself and the below 'answer' is for any googlers (hint, it's not really an answer):

The gitlab minikube setup spins up it's own ingress controllers that are bypassed, which is where TLS would normally be terminated. The '422' error is legitimate because `localhost:8080` does not provide a valid authenticity token to be processed by the host `gitlab.192.168.49.2.nip.io`

You can confirm this by tailing the logs of the webserver container (it outputs all logging to stdout).

So you can either disable to CSRF token check in the `omniauth.rb` file inside `config/initializers` and restart the rails instance, or move away from minikube (we used KinD to get this working) since ingress appeared to be broken with the gitlab setup.

Comment: any chance you can share the details on how you got things for Kind?